# Analog oscilloscope triggers

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, trigger

I have recently received an old 70's era Tektronix 465b dual trace oscilloscope.  Unfortunately I have close to no clue how to use it.

I understand the concept of triggering but this scope has two triggers, named trigger A and trigger B(DLY). Is trigger A for channel 1 and trigger B(DLY) for channel 2?

Some insight would be greatly appreciated as the manual is nearly useless in describing this.

Comment: http://www.kennethkuhn.com/hpmuseum/scans/Tek465b_op_.pdf

Comment: This is a very fine scope. Learn to use it, take care of it and find out how to repair it if it breaks. It will serve you well in electronics.

Comment: As @JohnHonniball says, that's a good solid scope, and it can be more trustworthy than a digital oscilloscope (no aliasing, for example). Also, unlike some slightly newer scopes from Tek, it's pretty repairable if you have the service manual.

Answer (score 4):

The 465B has two time base, A and B. The B time base is called delayed time base and can be used to zoom on a portion of a signal to see it in greater details. You can also trigger on this zoomed signal by using the trigger B (and the "DLY" is for "delayed" or "delay").

You can watch some videos from w2aew on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/w2aew/videos). He has differents tutorials on Tektronix oscilloscopes.

Answer (score 2):

In Tek's [Triggering Fundamentals](http://www.tek.com/dl/55W_17291_6_0.pdf), page. 12, it gives explanation about "Delaying triggering" and "AB.Sequence.Triggering". And i think you may need this old guy's service manual: http://bama.edebris.com/manuals/tek/465b.

Comment: That's a service manual.  I commented the user manual above